# Сделать задание — это сделать его правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, семантика

Диалог

*— Ты почему не делаешь задание, которое оставила тебе мама?*

*— А я уже всё сделала.*

*— Так быстро? Давай я проверю. Если ты сделала задание неправильно, мама будет тебя ругать, а ты опять будешь  плакать.*

*— Нет, не надо. Мама сказала мне сделать задание, но она не говорила, что его нужно сделать правильно.*

Конечно, ребенок  (ему почти 8 лет) хитрит, но почему ему удалась его уловка, где здесь речевая неточность? Разве «сделать задание» не означает, что его нужно сделать правильно?

Answer (score 2):

"Сделать задание" автоматически подразумевает "сделать правильно". Если я возьму доску и вколочу в неё гвоздь, это не будет означать, что я сделал табуретку, просто немного неправильно. Сделанное задание определяется по результату, а не по затраченным усилиям.

Приведённый диалог - это пример казуистики, и вряд ли эта уловка сработает. Мама разъяснит ошибку вербально, а папа может и тактильно.

Comment: А какая тут казуистика? Формально существуют три сочетания: сделать задание, сделать задание правильно или сделать его неправильно. К примеру, что там у нас? Вставить пропущенные буквы,   разделить слова для переноса? Пожалуйста, всё сделано. А правильно или нет – это уже другой вопрос. Вообще говоря, современные дети умнее и наблюдательнее, чем о них думают взрослые. Вернее сказать, ум у них другой:  они быстрее ориентируются в информационном пространстве. И вполне могут истолковать речевую ситуацию в свою пользу, если заметят в ней неточность.

Comment: Формальная логика из-за раннего общения с компьютерами им вполне доступна. Поэтому они могут и  не согласиться с тем, что  «сделать задание» автоматически означает «сделать задание правильно». 
Иногда такие эпизоды удивляют взрослых, но мне кажется, что дети обычно не демонстрируют  свои способности (они деликатны и снисходительны к нам), но иногда случается. К примеру, родители стараются определить способности ребенка, пробуют записывать его в разные кружки, и тот вроде бы соглашается (не хочет папу с мамой огорчать), а потом говорит подружкам – а от этого кружка я  «ловко отписалась».

Comment: @Sharon, человек не компьютер, и не руководствуется формальной логикой. Выполнение задания подразумевает как минимум искреннюю деятельность с реальным результатом, пусть и необязательно правильным. Имитация деятельности с заведомым отсутствием результата выполнением задания считаться не может.

Comment: Почему же имитация? Не исключено, что буквы вставлены верно, как нельзя исключить и обратное. Также если что-то сделано быстро, то это не означает, что оно сделано неверно, и наоборот. В данном случае ребенок просто хочет избежать двойного контроля, не считая его необходимым

Comment: @Sharon, если задание делается без цели сделать правильно, то это именно имитация деятельности. Даже если в результате ответ случайно совпадёт. Собственно, вы совершенно напрасно ориентируетесь тут на формальную логику, она применима только к искусственно упрощённым моделям. В обычной жизни большинство условий неявно подразумевается, иначе формулировка простейшего задания для ребёнка превратилась бы в огромную портянку с учётом всех возможных вариантов. Вы же не расписываете ребёнку процедуру закрывания кранов после мытья чашки? А для компьютера приходится всегда писать десятки условий.

Comment: Ничего не могу сказать про цель или ее отсутствие, так как  историю эту я слышала  в пересказе от родственников, хотя ребенка знаю лично.  Но в любом случае спасибо за Ваше мнение.